# Using pillow in python while trying to degrade image quality only does it once

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
def main():
    run = True
    loops = 0
    aoloops = 0
    loops = int(input("How many times do you want to loop: "))
    qual = int(input("Level of compression; 100 is highest quality, 1 is lowest quality: "))
    while run:
        im = Image.open("input.jpg" or "input.png")
        imo = im.convert('RGB')
        imo.save("output.jpg", quality=qual)
        im = Image.open("output.jpg")
        imo = im.convert('RGB')
        imo.save("output.jpg", quality=qual)
        aoloops += 1
        print(aoloops)
        if loops == aoloops:
            run = False
main()
```

im trying to get an input image, and while the loop is going continuously degrades the quality based on the qual value. The problem im having is that the output is always the same no matter how many times it loops. I'm not sure if i'm making a very simple mistake, but I cant find any examples of people doing anything similar to this. help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try moving the first Image.open, convert, and save to before the while loop. Each iteration of the while loop currently is starting with the unmodified input.jpg file.

Comment: That would seem like it would work, but unfortunately the file still acts like it was only looped once. I'm not sure if its actually the image library module acting up, or its my loop that's screwing things up. I've never done much with images in python so it's all kinda new for me